# How to select date from calendar that has readonly property using Playwright?

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright

I am new to the playwright framework came from protractor background and want to know the method for the selector to select a date in the playwright.

selctor.fill(date) //not working

Comment: It's that an HTML5 input or a widget?

Comment: @hardkoded basically it's a widget input field with the read-only property.

Comment: https://ibb.co/kDm2Mpq here is the SS of the element. https://ibb.co/t8f4w17 here is how the element is displaying in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

fill is used like this:

```
page.fill('selector', valueToFillWith)
```

so if date element is 'id="date"'

```
page.fill('[id="date"]', '08/21/2022')
```

https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-fill

Answer (score 0):

`page.fill('[id="date"]', '08/21/2022')` // not working

like this：

```
<input readonly="" placeholder="Select date" class="ant-calendar-picker-input ant-input" value="2022-02-25"\>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your date format is incorrect.

Try this:

```
await Page.FillAsync("YourSlector", "2022-02-25");
```